# How to check for null in column? and use other column instead?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How would I write a query that involves the following check:

if `colA` is null then `colB = colB1 + colB2`

if `colA` is not null then `colB = colA`

Answer (score 11):

According to SQL Standards (works with multiple flavors of SQL), you can use the `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT 
    colB = COALESCE (colA, (colB1 + colB2))
FROM theTable;
```

or a `CASE` expression (which is not so elegant but can be used for more complex conditions):

```
SELECT 
    colB = CASE WHEN colA IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN colA
                ELSE colB1 + colB2
           END
FROM theTable;
```

Using T-SQL (works with Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server)

```
SELECT 
    colB = ISNULL (colA, (colB1 + colB2))
FROM theTable;
```

However, you've not told us about any guarantees that either `colB1` or `colB2` will always have a value. If either of those are `NULL` then everything will be `NULL`. If that's the case then you can chain along conditions in `COALESCE` which would look like

```
colB = COALESCE(colA, (colB1 + colB2),0)
```

or using `ISNULL`

```
colB = ISNULL(ISNULL(colA, (colB1 + colB2)),0)
```

---

If you don't want to use it in the result but in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` condition, no change is needed. Either:

```
WHERE    colB = COALESCE (colA, (colB1 + colB2))
```

or:

```
WHERE    colB = CASE WHEN colA IS NOT NULL 
                       THEN colA
                     ELSE colB1 + colB2
                END
```

but you have one more option:

```
WHERE (  colB = colA
      OR colA IS NULL  AND  colB = colB1 + colB2
      )
```